# Is it okay to transport a DTO inside of a DTO?

Tags: design-patterns, services, dto

Let's suppose we have to entities, **X** and **Y** where **Y** is part of **X**, being this:

```
class X {
     private int fooX;
     private List<Y> fooY;
}

class Y {
      private long barX;
      private int barY;
      private short barX;
}
```

Wanting to transport data from a service to a different module, where the data relies from **X** entities, I'm creating a **DTO** for it

However, **X** has a list of **Y** entities inside of it, so simple data couldn't be used to represent them

So, is it okay that I create a DTO for **Y** and transport it inside of **X** DTO?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why would it not?

Comment: @Telastyn I think it was confusing me since I was looking to them as some big POJO's

Comment: @SEISCOOL They **are** POJOs.

Answer (score 2):

DTOs are used to transfer data between parties. As the definition suggests your objects are valid as long as they are designed for data transfer. That means they must carry no logic (or methods in other words), no private field (except back fields), and only use a set of limited data types (or other DTOs) because of serialization issues.

Another responsibility of Data Transfer Objects is to reduce the number of calls, because that helps both the simplicity and remote call numbers if your services are distributed. So you should try to get as much data as you can in a single call.

Finally, refactoring your objects in order to make your code **more readable** to achieve these purposes is absolutely a good practice. Feel free to extract classes from DTOs.

Comment: May be worth to mention as well: all DTO members should be public.  Here an interesting article that you could add to your answer: it explains very well what types should be used when composing a DTO: https://enroute.osgi.org/FAQ/420-dtos.html

Comment: Thanks @Christophe, That was a good article. I've edited my answer to add some points.